# ASP.NET Core 3 Logging errors when starting Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to get an API service running in ASP.NET Core 3 with logging, but I keep getting an error when trying to retrieve the ILogger from the Dependency service. I think I have followed the examples I can find, but I keep getting:

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger`1[GMT.Beacon.Service.Startup]' while attempting to activate 'GMT.Beacon.Service.Startup'.'"

I am using the default template to start the project, so it is setting up the web host through the default builder, which per the documentation should configure the Logging automatically.  Additionally, I have tried to manually add the providers but I get the same error.  I feel like I am missing something obvious, but can't figure out what.

Here is the Program.cs class that is erroring:

```
public class Program { 
    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        var logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Test log entry.");
        host.Run();
    }
}
```

In the Startup.cs class, here is the constructor:

```
public Startup(IConfiguration config, IHostEnvironment hosting, ILogger<Startup> logger) {
    _hosting = hosting;
    _config = config;
    _logger = logger;

    _logger.LogInformation($"{DateTime.UtcNow:R} - Starting (Environment={_hosting.EnvironmentName}; " + $"InformationalVersion={Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion};");
}
```

Based on the documentation I can find, this seems like it should work, but instead it throws the above error on line:

```
var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
```

I have also tried manually configuring the Logging (with the below code), but that is returning the same error.

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) => {
        logging.AddConfiguration(hostingContext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        logging.AddEventSourceLogger();
        logging.AddConsole();
        logging.AddDebug();
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
    });
```

Does anyone see a problem with this setup, or know how to correctly configure the logging subsystem in ASP.NET Core 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something that's changed in ASP.NET Core 3. See the announcement [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/353):

> TLDR: The only types the generic Host supports for Startup constructor injection are `IHostEnvironment`, `IWebHostEnvironment`, and `IConfiguration`. Applications using WebHost are unaffected.

`ILogger<T>` is injectable into `Configure`, so you can access it from there to log your startup message:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILogger<Startup> logger)
{
    logger.LogInformation(...);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET Core 2.x, logging is created at the host builder. This means that logging is available through DI by default and can be injected into the Startup class:

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly ILogger<Startup> _logger;


    public Startup(ILogger<Startup> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

}
```